# Using abbreviation to insert comment

Tags: vim

I’m trying to set up an abbreviation in my `.vimrc` that will insert a comment template for heading-level comments in my CSS files.

The comment I want to insert is:

```
/* ==========================================================================
   #
   ========================================================================== */
```

I will then jump back to the `#` and add my title there (e.g. `BUTTONS`).

The abbreviation I have attempted to set up looks like this:

```
iab comsec·
\/* ==========================================================================
\<Cr>#
\<Cr>========================================================================== */
```

(Where `·` represents a trailing space.)

Right away this *feels* pretty crude, but the specific problem is that if try and drop a `comsec` in my CSS, it starts wrapping it in *more* comments. The output looks like this:

```
/* ==========================================================================
 * #
 * ========================================================================== */
```

Notice the two `*` at the beginnings of lines 2 and 3?

Is there a way to tell vim not to try and be clever and to just drop in exactly what I’ve told it? A way to prevent vim from trying to wrap comments around the comment?

I’m not a particularly hardcore vim user, so there’s every chance I’m overcomplicating things, or missing something obvious, or using the wrong tool for the job.

Thanks!

Comment: `set paste`.  However, you might consider using a snippet solution instead.  They are pretty good these days.

Comment: If you don't want it to automatically insert * in comments, or leading tabs/spaces in statements, you can use ` set paste.` by the way are you looking for a solution to insert the multiline comment or you just wanted to remove the star alone?

Comment: @SibiCoder Can I tell an abbreviation to set and unset paste? Or do I need to set and unset it myself before and after calling the abbreviation? Also, I want to inset all of the multiline comment.

Comment: You have to give this command in vimrc file (anywhere in the file) for it to take effect every time. If you want to do only once, you can put that in command line. Iabbr will not work if you give set paste. My question is, do you want a easy way to insert the multiline comment or are you searching for a particular solution with the steps you followed?

Comment: @SibiCoder I’m looking for the best way to insert that multiline comment. If the best solution isn’t an abbreviation, I’m open to hearing alternatives :)

Comment: @csswizardry there are several ways to do it. I have come with a function temporarily. I will improve the answer once I fi d the best one.

Comment: @csswizardry I have edited my answer ! hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

If you are the type of person who can keep track of your personal utilities, this isn't so fancy but works. You can import the output of an external command into your buffer, so I put a mapping like this in my .vimrc file:

```
"bc = block comment
map ,bc :read! python ~/my_personal_utils/insert_css_comment.py
```

So, I just have to type ",bc" to add the comment.  On my Mac at least, this leaves me hanging in command mode, so that my cursor is after '.py' and I can quickly type an argument like BUTTONS (i.e. the python script takes an optional argument).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better and simple way to to insert your comment which check everytime if the line is surrounded by the comment template.

All you have to do is to write your comment on new line and then press <kbd>;</kbd> during the **insert mode**. (*you can change the character <kbd>;</kbd> by
any combination you want.*)

The comment template is set by the variable `l:start`, `l:begin`, `l:end` 
so you can change the number of **spaces** or **=** as you like.
If you would like to change the template completely keep in mind that you need to change also the regular expressions for the variables `l:matchprev`, `l:matchhier`, `l:matchnext` .

```
inoremap <silent> ; <Esc>mx:call Comment()<cr>i<Right>

function! Comment()
    let l:start= "/* ====="
    let l:begin=" # "
    let l:end=  " ==== */"
    let l:next=getline(line(".")+1)
    let l:hier=getline(line("."))
    let l:prev=getline(line(".")-1)
    let l:matchnext= matchstr( l:next , '^\s*=\+\s*\*/\s*$')
    let l:matchhier= matchstr( l:hier , '^\s*#\s*.*$')
    let l:matchprev= matchstr( l:prev , '^\s*/\*\s*=\+\s*$')
    if l:matchnext != '' && l:matchprev != '' && l:matchhier != ''
        return 0
    else
        execute ":s:^.*$:".l:start."\r".l:begin."&\r".l:end."\r:"
        "the number 3 is the length of the variable l:begin
        normal! `xj3l

    endif
endfunction
```

write this code in another file *scriptname* and then you can use the mapping in any css file by typing in the command mode first `:so scriptname`

Another alternative is to put all that simply in your `.vimrc` file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to do that.

```
      :function! Comment()
      :normal! i/*
      :normal! 80a=
      :normal! o#
      :normal! o
      :normal! 80i=
      :normal! a*/
      :endfunction
```

You can put this in vimrc file and create a command or map for this.

Command

```
        :cmap comsec call Comment()
```

You can keep the cursor on a line and then call this command.

Or an in insert mode mapping

```
        :imap comsec <ESC>:comsec<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternatives I'd suggest [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) for commenting/uncommenting with a few key strokes.

Or, even better, [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). In which you can easily make your own template for those headings:

1. open a .css file
2. exec command `: UltiSnipsEdit`
3. create your own snip:

> snippet heading "heading comments"
>
> /* ===================================
>
> * ${1}
>
> * =================================== */
>
> endsnippet